# Add calculated column data with decimals

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, calculated-column

Is there any way to sum all values in one calculated column without losing decimal data?

We're using an XPath expression and it loses all decimal information.
Where @myField is one calculated column

```
<xsl:value-of select="@myfield" />
```

And at the end the end of the group structure

```
<xsl:value-of select="sum($nodeset/@myfield)" />
```

I assume the problem is because it's a calculated column as if we use a numeric column it works fine.

Thanks

**Edit:**

There's three level of grouping (username, year, month)
The formula is inside the last level.

Comment: Where exactly are you using that formula? Please provide more detail.

Comment: I've added a little bit of more info, if you need anything else please be a little bit more specific as I'm not the one developing this feature. Thank you

Comment: It is still not clear where you are using this function. You have tagged with three tags, but there are very many different places where such a function could be applied. Please provide more details. Are you using an XSLT list view? Or a DVWP? Or custom code? What is the data source? What is the query? What are the field data types? What is the formula for the calculated column? How is it stored?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was happening because of the format of the numbers, first I tried unsuccessfully to change the format numbers are displayed. As It didn't work I tried to format the data passed to the sum function.

After a while I realized that there was another problem because I wasn't allowed to use functions inside the expression in the select attribute.

I was able to iterate through the values inside $nodeset and print foreach one this

```
<xsl:value-of select="number(translate(@myfield,',','.'))" />
```

with no error, but when trying to use the function it wouldn't work.

```
<xsl:value-of select="sum($nodeset/number(translate(@myfield,',','.')))" />
```

I used the first way showed in the answer for this question and worked like a charm.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/647991/summing-numbers-with-comma-as-decimal-separator-in-xslt

Answer (score 0):

Is the calculated column formatted as a number?  You could try casting the values within the XPath:

```
<xsl:value-of select="number(@myfield)" />
```